# Chrome packaged app AngularJS boilerplate template

Tags: angularjs, templates, boilerplate, google-chrome-app

Is there an AngularJS Chrome packaged app template available? Looking for a similar solution to ng-boilerplate but for Chrome packaged apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few projects out there that may help you get started.

http://extensionizr.com

https://github.com/mahemoff/chrome-boilerplate

https://github.com/Swader/ChromeSkel_a

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples

Comment: OPs question was about AngularJS. Not one of these use AngularJS.